# Can't login after removing python3 and reinstalling

Tags: 18.04, python, login, boot-repair, recovery-mode

I removed python3 without knowing it might cause problems. Then I reinstalled python3,  ubuntu-desktop and gnome in recovery mode and also did package repair. Now i can see the login page but when i enter my password, it reloads the same page and can't login. Also mouse clicks don't work. What should I do to fully recover?

Comment: You may need to reinstall the OS. Several components of Ubuntu require python to function properly. There is probably not just one single thing you would need to do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I performed the steps described here: https://towardsdatascience.com/fixing-a-broken-ubuntu-gui-5ce3656922f5

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo reboot
```

Comment: If this has completely solved the issue, then count yourself very, *very* lucky. As Nmath stated in response to your question, generally the OS needs to be reinstalled when Python is removed and all the warnings ignored ...

Comment: Yeah definitely... But I think you just shouldn't be able to remove python as it is a so fundamental element of the os.

Comment: Linux doesn't nanny you or hold your hand like MacOS or Windows. If you give it instructions, it will obey. With great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Well just prompting is not nannying...

Comment: If you uninstalled it with `apt`, then you were informed which packages would be removed. You also used sudo which means you know what you're doing.  If you used the software center, you were similarly informed and prompted for authorization. I'd suggest taking this as a lesson in not removing/changing things if you aren't sure what they do and the full consequences of those actions.  If you come away expecting a prompt to tell you that you're doing something bad, you're unfortunately going to find yourself repeating this situation.  Linux is not Windows. Lots of things depend on others.